# What to unit-test in a file managing application

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic

Imagine a GUI file manager which recursively scans directory structures and provides different operations on it. What parts should be unit-tested? I only can think of a very small part, because GUI is not unit-testable (but GUI-testable) and file system stuff also is not unit-testable, because the results may depend on the used file system and file operations are slow, too slow for unit-testing.

Answer (score 1):

- You can unit-test you GUI logic if you use the MVP (Model-View-Presenter) pattern, in its [Passive View form](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PassiveScreen.html). You unit-test your Presenter classes, which are independent of your GUI framework
- You can unit-test code which accesses the filesystem if you stub out/mock your File class. Mock frameworks like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) are great for this

Comment: Regarding unit-testing GUI logic of a MVP pattern: did you ever *tried* that yourself for a non-trivial application? Was it worth the effort?

Comment: Yes I did, and I can assure you it's worth it. I work in medical imaging apps so testing is paramount. I unit-tested the GUI for an X-Ray driven panel which informs, among other things, if the patient is being irradiated. Can't mess that up!

Comment: Yes, I test that kind of logic, but I don't do it for every event of every single dialog/control; I only unit-test the most important use cases. For example, if the XRayEnabled event is received and the imaging device is Enabled, x-rays are irradiated. I thought of all the ways the GUI could respond to that and its variations, including errors/exceptions and iterated over that. If I detect code duplication, I refactor it out after making all test pass, as usual

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that FS operations are too slow for unit testing.

Does your GUI invoke API calls, which in turn invoke your FS methods?  If so, you an easily test your FS API.  Unit tests can certainly do something like create a `test-sandbox` directory under some directory and operate on that.

The key thing is to have the unit test always create the initial directory and file structure, so that the tests are repeatable.

Comment: A unit test should not access the file system; if it does, I consider it an integration test. See my answer. I think Michael Feathers, the author of `Working effectively with Legacy Code`, is of the same opinion

Comment: Furthermore, accessing the FS directly tends to have the tests share state through it (i.e. one test changes the files which are read by another one). True, you can use [Setup]-[Teardown] to delete used files and copy fresh files in, but that's where it's bound to get slow, if it's done for every test

Comment: @dario, its not going to be slow enough to make people not unit test, as long as people are reasonable.  Yes creating 10000 files will be slow, but creating 10 won't.  And setup/teardown can clean things up just fine, if you create a starting directory for each test.

Comment: Granted, but the ideal for running unit tests is instantaneous feedback (i.e. run all tests and get results right away). Accessing the FS goes against that. Anyway, we can agree to disagree :)

Comment: @dario, agreed.  The reality IMHO though is any sufficiently large project its going to take a few seconds for all tests to run.  And again, IMHO waiting 1-3 seconds for tests to complete is OK.

Comment: File system tests may fail because of different file systems (think about case-insensitive/case-preserving and case-sensitive). The tricky stuff which IMHO should be tested is to handle these border cases, not the obvious trivial ones.